# C++ Object inaccessible

Tags: c++, oop, object, scope

I'm trying to reference an object in a function and it is giving me an "Object is inaccessible" error. Here is the header and cpp file in question.

customer header file below. I've put the object declaration at the bottom.

```
#pragma once

#include "bankAccount.h"
#include "checkingAccount.h"
#include "savingsAccount.h"
#include "address.h"

using namespace std;

class customer {

public:

   customer(void);
   customer(string,string);
   ~customer(void);

   void setName(string n);
   string getName();

   void withdrawChecking(double);
   void wihdrawSavings(double);

   double depositSavings(double);

   string print();

   private:

   string name

   checkingAccount myChecking;
   savingsAccount mySavings;

};
```

Here is the cpp file. I've bolded the problem statement.

```
#include "customer.h"
#include "checkingAccount.h"

customer::customer(void){

}

customer::customer(string n, string ac){

name = n;

mySavings.setAccount(ac);

myChecking.setAccount(ac);

}

void customer::setName(string n){

name = n;
}

string customer::getName(){

return name;
}

  void withdrawChecking(double w){

myChecking.withdrawChecking(w);
}
```

So what is wrong with this last statement and my header?

Sorry for bad styling... first time posting a question.

Comment: you declared withdrawChecking as a function, you should declare it inside the custumer using the :: operator to define the scope..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `customer` on the front of `withdrawChecking`. It should be:

```
void customer::withdrawChecking(double w)
```

Comment: Wow thank you. Copy and paste always leads to fail for me. Thanks so much.